# Creating a web Api and trying to run it from iis doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

When i'm launch my web api application from visual studio all seems to work perfect. But when i'm trying to publish it and run it via IIS7 it doesnt work.

First step i create a controller with name Person.

```
public class PersonController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Person
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Person/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/Person
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/Person/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Person/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
```

Then i'm choosing Publish, and selecting IIS,FTP,etc. Then i'm selecting Filesystem and rooting my path:

[image: Path]

Here is my files inside folder

[image: Files]

Then inside IIS i choose add new web site:

[image: Config]

Now when i'm opening and trying to access in my controller i'm getting error below:
http://localhost:8080/FirstSite/api/person

[image: ErrorImage]

Is there something am i doing wrong?  Is there something wrong with my files which i export?

[image: Chack configuration]

Comment: You should use a URL like `http://localhost:8080/api/person`.

Answer (score 1):

If you added a website and left the hostname blank, you should access your API at http://localhost:8080/api/person

Comment: Check if the website is using the appropriate Application pool.

.Net Framework Version: 4.0
Pipeline Mode: Integrated

Comment: I change it, but i have the same issue. If i will run http://192.168.0.214:8080/HtmlPage1.html my page opens. But if i will run http://192.168.0.214:8080/api/person it doenst

Comment: Is this the first time you will use your IIS with ASPNet? If yes, you might need to register your IIS.

You will need to execute the following:
aspnet_regiis.exe -i
aspnet_regiis.exe -ga {user}
aspnet_regbrowsers.exe -i

See here for details
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229858.aspx

Comment: It didn't worked. I can't understand where is my problem

Comment: If you've done that and still not working, try running iisreset.exe

Comment: I'm still getting error 404 not found... Also please look picture in question. Does it have to do with my problem?

Answer (score 1):

try adding the below to your hosted web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Here is what i cave now in web config:  <system.webServer>
  
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="Aspnet" path="*.asax" verb="*" type="*.asax" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just neet to set identity in advanced settings as Local System
[image: img]